# Asyncronously receiving data in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm looking for the best way to constantly check if data has been sent to our ASP.NET MVC application from a server.  I would like to asynchronously check for data and update the view when data has been read.

I'm currently using a `TcpClient` to make a connection, and making the connection in the inherited custom base controller.  Currently though I have to refresh the page for the updating of the view to take place.

Would there be a proper AJAX solution? or do I need to move the connection to the `ActionMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use jQuery to query some action at a specified interval and update the page accordingly.

I don't know what kind of data you're talking about, but let's look at a simple example.  From you're question, it sounds to me like you're trying to do the following:

Suppose you are building Twitter and want to show the newest Tweets on the homepage.  Well, you could have a script that just does a jQuery.GetJSON call to some URL (let's call it twitter.com/latest5tweets) that gets the latest 5 tweets.  Then you would have a callback function that would take those tweets and paint them on the screen -- perhaps using some sort of nifty slide effect to remove the older ones from the screen and add the new ones.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes this does help. JQuery may be the best way to go. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 4):

For complete solution use this free library : [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com)